# Type mismatch in example from Learning Haskell through Data Analysis

Tags: haskell

I have a *basic* knowledge of Haskell (LYAH) and wanted to look at this book to expand my Haskell, plus the general topic is something I enjoy. However it didn't take long before I ran into a type issue :

```
applyToColumnInCSVFile :: ([String] -> b) -> FilePath -> String -> IO (Either String b)
applyToColumnInCSVFile func inFileName column = do
  input <- readFile inFileName
  let records = parseCSV inFileName input
  return $ either handleCSVError (\csv -> applyToColumnInCSV func csv column) records
    where
      handleCSVError = Left "This does not appear to be a CSV file."
```

It complains that handleCSVError is expected to be `Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError` but actually is Either [Char] b0' .

This is where I hit a wall on trying to figure out the solution to these error messages. I can actually follow the code at a high level in this book, but if I make a small error in writing the code, or there is some other small problem I can not so easily recover.

In the above I have possibly narrowed it down to an issue with parseCSV because when I check that :

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-0.1.2/docs/Text-CSV.html

It shows it can return a ParseError, but I don't know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: `parseCSV` isn't your issue. Think more closely about the type of `either`

Comment: That... is not what the error says. 1. Read it carefully; GHC's error messages are generally both very precise and very informative. 2. Proper etiquette here on SO is to copy-and-paste errors; attempts to summarize them when you don't understand them in the first place are doomed to failure.

Comment: There's quite a lot going wrong here. You need to take this function apart and study the types of the things you're using. Copying and modifying solutions from the book may not be a good idea if you're still new to the language.

Comment: I second the comment by @DanielWagner. We can't reproduce your error using GHC since you did not provide the full code, nor a MCVE. And, even if we could, you should try to minimize the effort required for an answer: it costs you only a little time to cut&paste the error, and point out the relevant line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on this part of your code:

```
return $ either handleCSVError (\csv -> applyToColumnInCSV func csv column) records
  where
    handleCSVError = Left "This does not appear to be a CSV file."
```

As @DanielWagner noted in the comments, you misquoted your error message which actually reads:

> • Couldn't match expected type `parsec3.1.13.0:Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError -> Either String b`
>                     with actual type `Either [Char] b0`

The error message continues to point you to your definition of `handleCSVError`. You didn't apply a type to it, but let's add one to make more sense of the error message:

```
return $ either handleCSVError (\csv -> applyToColumnInCSV func csv column) records
  where 
    handleCSVError :: Either String _
    handleCSVError = Left "This does not appear to be a CSV file."
```

I'm using a type hole for the right component of the either since we don't actually care what it is here, and remember that in Haskell `[Char]` and `String` are the same type.

Now, let's look at the type of [`either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=either).

The first argument of `either` is a *function* which takes in something of the left type of your `Either`, and returns the output type. But you've defined `handleCSVError` as a static function with no arguments. It has the correct output type `c` of `Either String _` from your larger function, but doesn't specify the argument. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Use [`const`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=const): `... either (const handleCSVError) ...`
2. Throw away the first argument in your definition of `handleCSVError`:

   ```
   handleCSVError :: ParseError -> Either String _
   handleCSVError _ = Left "This does not appear to be a CSV file."
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something that simple, I just can't parse out the error messages that readily yet. Now it is clear, either required a function (desiring to generate a Left in this case) and I was passing it a Left directly, hence the mismatch. In the book code, it actually had handleCSVError == Left "This does not appear to be a CSV file." which just threw an error directly as it could not parse it. I guess that was a typo,  _ = vs == .